# Error using Algebraic Constraint block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I wanted to implement a complex equation using Algebraic Constraint block, but I am getting an error which is as follows

> Trouble solving algebraic loop containing 'trial1/Algebraic Constraint1/Initial Guess' at time 0. Stopping simulation. There may be a singularity in the solution. If the model is correct, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances)

The equation I'm trying to solve is

```
w1*r3*cosβ= w2r4(sinw2t + (r4*sin(2*w2*t)*cosβ)/(2*l2)).
```

Basically I have to put values of all parameters as some constant and get a graph of w2 vs time...

Your help would be of immense value to me.
Also suggest if I can solve by any other method.

[image: Shows the implementation of the above equation]

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to use the result of the solve block before it is computed. If possible this is avoided by adding a delay into the feedback path, but i suppose that would alter the behaviour of your model.

Have a look at this:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95310-what-are-algebraic-loops-in-simulink-and-how-do-i-solve-them